# How to close bootstrap modal pop up and pass the id to next page in php

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, cakephp, modal-dialog

I want to search a record for this i am using modal pop up that is taking name and i want after entering the name and clicking on the submit button modal popup closes and a new form opens and displays data that has been searched from the database. Please give me solution.

```
<div id="EmployeeSearch" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" data-width="600">
<form action="class/insert_outward.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h3 style="background:url(img/create_user.png) no-repeat left center; padding-left: 46px;height: 39px; ">Search Employee</h3>
  </div>
 <div id="task_status" style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:12px; margin:0 0 0 10px; color:red;"></div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span12">
     <p> <input type="text" class="span12" name="slipno[]" id="slipno[]" placeholder="Enter Name of Employee"/> </p>
     </div>
   </div>

  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Close</button>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary"/>
     <!--<button type="button"  onClick="task_sent();" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>-->


  </div>
 </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it by AJAX

**Submitting search and closing model**

```
$(function(){
   $('#EmployeeSearch .btn.btn-primary').on('click', function(){
       var nameData =  $(this).val();
       //Make an AJAX request
       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "class/insert_outward.php", // URL of search 
        data: { name: nameData  }
         })
       .done(function( msg ) {
          //Insert result
          $("#resultModal .modal-body").html( msg ); // Insert result into result model body 
          //Close the Model 
          $("#EmployeeSearch").modal('hide');
          //Open result model 
          $("#resultModal").modal('show');
       });
   });
});
```

**Displaying results in another model**

Add a model like below in html

```
  <!-- Result Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="resultModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
     <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Results</h4>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body">

       </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"   data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

      </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```